# :data() selector should be recognized?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery-1.11.1 and I try to use the :data selector, described on

https://api.jqueryui.com/data-selector/

trying to find all elements having a certain key like this:

```
var elements = $(':data(kendoMobileScroller)');
```

but all I get is an error saying:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: data

Shouldn´t there be such a selector?

Comment: Are you including jQuery UI?! Because this is a pseudo selector added by jQuery UI, not jQuery

Comment: `jQuery` and `jQuery UI` are two different library's

Comment: please add the html as well

Comment: @user25: the HTML is irrelevant for this problem.

Comment: The URL was a good hint actually :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to include jQuery UI in order to get `:data` pseudo selector working, e.g:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Or just extend jQuery:

```
$.extend( $.expr[ ":" ], {
    data: $.expr.createPseudo ?
        $.expr.createPseudo(function( dataName ) {
            return function( elem ) {
                return !!$.data( elem, dataName );
            };
        }) :
        // support: jQuery <1.8
        function( elem, i, match ) {
            return !!$.data( elem, match[ 3 ] );
        }
});
```

### DEMO

Comment: Do you know why is it included in jqueryui and not jquery?

Comment: @AndersLindén Because this is a jQuery UI feature, not from jQuery core plugin. Why jQuery team doesn't include it, is only depending their own choice.

Answer (score 2):

I got the error

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: data

because the `:data() Selector` was not found.

With the Rails Asset Pipeline and Yarn, I needed to add `//= require jquery-ui/ui/data` to the `application.js` manifest. This ensures the jquery-ui `:data() Selector` would be found.

With other build systems like Webpack, you might need to `require('jquery-ui/ui/data')`, or build against `jquery-ui-dist` or `jquery-ui-bundle`. [See this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39230057/40785).

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked a while ago but for anyone who chances on this you can use a css attribute selector

```
$('[data-kendoMobileScroller]')
```