# jquery-ui and webpack, how to manage it into module?

Tags: jquery-ui, webpack

any idea how to deal with that ? I mean jquery-ui seems not to be amd and I don't know how to manage that , any idea ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

youre in luck I did this just that yesterday, it's rather easy.

```
npm install --save jquery jquery-ui
```

Make sure that you have jquery aliased to resolve with the plugin in the webpack.config.js

```
...
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      "$":"jquery",
      "jQuery":"jquery",
      "window.jQuery":"jquery"
    }),
...
```

Then include two aliases in the webpack.config.js

1. The node_modules folder
2. The jquery-ui folder

``````

```
resolve : {
    alias: {
      // bind version of jquery-ui
      "jquery-ui": "jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js",      
      // bind to modules;
      modules: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules"),
```

Make sure that jquery  gets loaded first in your app startup file.

```
var $ = require("jquery"),
        require("jquery-ui");
```

If you need to use a theme configure the css-loader and the file-loader. Don't forget to npm install those loaders.

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" },
      { test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i, loader:"file" },
```

And use in your app startup file.

```
require("modules/jquery-ui/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css");
require("modules/jquery-ui/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.theme.css");
```

Comment: What's the app startup file? If you initialize $ there, how can you make it global for all your files?

Comment: Are you using npm? jquery-ui.js doesn't come with it

Comment: The startup file is the file when you do node app.js, the entry file of your app. When you use provide plugin, that's how you make it global for any file processed by webpack. For all the other files you just require it. Yes, I am using npm you need to require jquery and jquery-ui and all the others like webpack and the loaders you use before this solution works.

Comment: The answer below is only for when using the bundle and not appropriate when you npm install jQuery because that way you don't get the bundle but the package!

Comment: @WendellMuntslag I just had to add new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      "$":"jquery",
      "jQuery":"jquery",
      "window.jQuery":"jquery"
    }), to my webpack.config.js.  Did need the alias. It worked.  Thanks.

Comment: @FrancoisRichard This should not be the accepted would consider changing to what is now the correct answer, ABH's answer

Comment: why would you have to "Make sure that jquery gets loaded first in your app startup file"? Isn't the whole point of ProvidePlugin that you don't have to do this? Description is "Automatically load modules instead of having to import or require them everywhere."

Answer (score 97):

`jquery-ui-dist` and `jquery-ui-bundle` do not seem to be maintained by the jquery-ui team. After jquery-ui v1.12 Its possible to use the official `jquery-ui` package from npm with webpack.

Update jquery-ui to 1.12 by updating `package.json` and `npm install`.

Then you can `require` each widget like this.

```
require("jquery-ui/ui/widgets/autocomplete");
require("jquery-ui/ui/widgets/draggable");
```

If you have used `require("jquery-ui")` before you need to replace it with separate imports for each widget. I think the new way is better because it will bundle only the code for the widget we need to use.

See [documentation](https://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.12/#official-package-on-npm) on using the 1.12 official npm package.

Comment: this answer helped me the most, but mine still didn't work until I had it dynamically loaded. it couldn't be required during compile time, because the draggable widget kept looking for a jQuery object. (not global.jQuery or window.jQuery). so i had it required after the page load

Comment: @NnennaUde does adding `require('jquery');` before `require("jquery-ui/ui/widgets/draggable");` work?

Comment: No, that wasn't the problem. Anyway, since then, I have been able to get it to work. It's still a mystery what the problem actually was.

However, I did have issues getting it to work in a jsdom testing environment. That same error was showing up again. `$.widget( "ui.draggable", $.ui.mouse, {

TypeError: Cannot read property 'mouse' of undefined`

However, I was able to fix it by requiring all its dependencies as follows:
`require('jquery-ui/ui/version');
require('jquery-ui/ui/plugin');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widget');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/mouse')`;

Comment: So bitter about how hard it is to find documentation for NPM installation instructions on JQuery-UI. I can't wait until the day I can murder this library from my current project!

Comment: how to include css files of autocomplete ?

Comment: This is the correct answer, man, why it was so hard to find?

Comment: ikr? I guess most the people who still use jquery-ui, use it from the cdn instead of bundling? so jquery-ui people pay little attention to bundling.

Comment: where do the require statements go? in webpack.config.js? app.js? somewhere else?

Comment: Also, shouldn't we prefer "import" as of ES2015? https://insights.untapt.com/webpack-import-require-and-you-3fd7f5ea93c0

Answer (score 89):

For some reason `jquery-ui` didn't play nice with webpack. I had to require `jquery-ui-bundle` instead.

`npm i -S jquery-ui-bundle`

and then require it after jquery e.g.

```
require('jquery');
require('jquery-ui-bundle');
```

Comment: Thank you. Saved me so much headache. Seems the jquery-ui package doesn't contain a ready build jquery-ui.js file :/

Comment: this worked for my electron app deployment as well.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you please extend your answer with a working example of `webpack.config.js` with jquery and `jquery-ui`?

Comment: `jquery-ui` now works nice with webpack. See my answer.

Comment: I spent hours trying to figure out why jquery-ui throws errors during vanilla js migration to Create React App... This answer made my day!!

Answer (score 21):

### webpack-jquery-ui

[**webpack-jquery-ui**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-jquery-ui)
- use this plugin, e.g. if you use Rails 5, run

```
 yarn add webpack-jquery-ui
```

When jQuery UI plugin starts, it checks if jquery provided, so

Add this code to your webpacker configuration file (shared.js - if you use it with Rails 5)

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      "window.jQuery": "jquery'",
      "window.$": "jquery"
  })
]
```

Add these lines into your app code.

```
require('webpack-jquery-ui');
require('webpack-jquery-ui/css');
```

**to fix `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` in `jquery.ajax`**

You have to pass an `authenticity_token` parameter with all your `PUT`, `POST` and `DELETE` requests.

To do that you can usually fetch it from the header with `$('[name="csrf-token"]')[0].content`

So your request would look something like:

```
var that = this;
$.ajax({
  url: navigator_item.url,
  data: { authenticity_token: $('[name="csrf-token"]')[0].content},
  method: 'DELETE',
  success: function(res) {
   ...
  }
});
```

### **I include jQuery into my application in another way**

Instead of using:

```
plugins: [
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({...
```

You should add 'jquery': 'jquery/src/jquery' to aliases in the webpack config file:

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
        'jquery': 'jquery/src/jquery'
    }
  }
```

It will provide module name 'jquery'. jQuery UI checks this name on init.

Then in you app.js file you write:

```
import $ from 'jquery'

import 'webpack-jquery-ui/css'
import 'webpack-jquery-ui/sortable' // if you need only sortable widget.

window.jQuery = $;
window.$ = $; // lazy fix if you want to use jQuery in your inline scripts.
```

Comment: Thanks, Stanley! Your second solution with adding an alias did work for me

Answer (score 20):

The accepted answer doesn't work for me as the jQuery-ui package on NPM isn't pre-built and therefore doesn't contain `jquery-ui.js`; the package will either need built before use or all the widgets included/used individually.

Quickest way I got the whole package working was by first downloading the distributable version:

```
npm install jquery-ui-dist --save
```

I needed to add an alias for `jquery-ui-dist` to avoid a 'Cannot find module' error (using just `require('jquery-ui-dist')` won't work, because the .js filename is different), by adding this to `webpack.config.js`:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        'jquery-ui': 'jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js'
    }
},
```

Finally, you can use this in the .js file where the modules are loaded:

```
var jQuery = require('jquery');
require('jquery-ui');
```

Alternatively, you can avoid having to `require` the scripts when loading the modules, and having to declare jQuery as a variable, by using ProvidePlugin in your webpack.config.js:

```
 plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        'jQuery': 'jquery',
        '$': 'jquery',
        'global.jQuery': 'jquery'
    })
],
```

Comment: I can't make it work. Using webpack.ProvidePlugin it exposes correctly "jQuery" and "$" variables to the window, but without "jquery-ui" addons. If I console.log($.ui) it gives undefined. @chrBrd any idea?
Which version of webpack you used?

Comment: It would have been version 1.x?? - whatever was current when I wrote the  answer. Does it work if you use `require` instead of ProvidePlugin?

Comment: You can use `require('jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js');` instead of the alias.

Answer (score 4):

The steps that worked for me (in a Rails 5.1.6 project) aren't identical to any of the above:

Install jquery and jquery-ui: `yarn add jquery` and `yarn add jquery-ui`

Add the following to the webpack config (i.e. in `/config/webpack/environment.js`) to globally set $ and jquery and jQuery:

```
environment.plugins.prepend(
  'Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery'
  })
)
```

Require whichever individual jquery-ui package(s) you want, at the top of your pack (e.g at the top of `/javascript/packs/application.js`:

```
require("jquery-ui/ui/widgets/sortable")
```

Then you can call, for example, `$('.selector').sortable()` anywhere in your pack.

Answer (score 4):

add jquery in your node_modules using;

```
npm install --save jquery jquery-ui
```

and add externals in your webpack.config.js like;

...

```
  externals: {
// require("jquery") is external and available
//  on the global var jQuery
"jquery": "jQuery",
"jquery-ui": "jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js", 
}
```

it worked for me

Comment: strange adding jquery to external it worked

Answer (score 2):

You should import all of these and check which ones you really need.

```
require('jquery-ui/ui/core.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/data.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/form.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/form-reset-mixin.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/focusable.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/disable-selection.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/plugin.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/labels.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/position.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/scroll-parent.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/tabbable.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/unique-id.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widget.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/accordion.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/autocomplete.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/button.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/checkboxradio.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/controlgroup.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/dialog.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/draggable.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/droppable.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/menu.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/mouse.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/progressbar.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/resizable.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/selectable.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/selectmenu.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/slider.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/sortable.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/spinner.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/tabs.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/tooltip.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/effect.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-blind.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-bounce.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-clip.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-drop.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-explode.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-fade.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-fold.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-highlight.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-puff.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-pulsate.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-scale.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-shake.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-size.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-slide.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/effects/effect-transfer.js');
require('jquery-ui/ui/vendor/jquery-color/jquery.color.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have looked through many forums and websites with descriptions and solutions to this problem. Unfortunately, none of the answers seemed correct or caused other problems, and that was not the point. That's why I started looking for my own solution. Here is my solution to this problem.

In my application I use webpack and several pages, not mal, each with a different entry. Because not every website requires certain libraries and there is no point in adding them there. I use autocomplet with jQuery-ui on several sites and unfortunately, despite adding this library via yarn or npm to the project, sites using autocomplete reported that autocomplete is not a function, i.e. they do not recognize it. To get around this, I added something like this in e.g. app.js file:

```
import autocomplete from 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/autocomplete';
window.autocomplete = autocomplete;
```

Of course, the jQuery-ui library must also be added:

```
import 'jquery-ui';
```

This solution worked for me. I hope this helps someone.