# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function(anonymous function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, datepicker

I found few answers on stack overflow but still cant resolve my problem.
I am running on Django but I dont think it is relevant for this error.

I try to make work my date picker java script but I am getting the error

1:27 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function(anonymous function) @ 1:27fire @ jquery-1.9.1.js:1037self.fireWith @ jquery-1.9.1.js:1148jQuery.extend.ready @ jquery-1.9.1.js:433completed @ jquery-1.9.1.js:103
jquery-2.1.0.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: POST "https://localhost:26143/skypectoc/v1/pnr/parse".l.cors.a.crossDomain.send @ jquery-2.1.0.min.js:4o.extend.ajax @ jquery-2.1.0.min.js:4PNR.findNumbers @ pnr.js:43parseContent @ contentscript.js:385processMutatedElements @ contentscript.js:322

This is all my scripts :

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.dateinput').datepicker({ format: "yyyy/mm/dd" });
    }); 
</script>

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->

<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Just to make our placeholder images work. Don't actually copy the next line! -->
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/vendor/holder.min.js"></script>
<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#extra-content").hide();
        $("#toggle-content").click(function(){
            $("#extra-content").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

any feedback will be very appreciated

Comment: You should only call jQuery once for a start

Comment: Well, since you've got the proper jquery-ui.js included and it is still saying that datepicker() is not a function, is it possible that your selector is incorrect?  Does $('.dateinput') exist after page load or is it being added dynamically and double check that it's a classname and not it's id (( $('#dateinput') ))

Comment: Actually when I removed the includes of jquery     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>


I am not getting this error any more , thanks Andy

Comment: whats your html looks like ? do you have "dateinput" class assigned to the input field ?

Comment: Since I'm using Webpack, I needed to use jquery-ui-bundle instead. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39230057/470749

Answer (score 89, accepted):

## What went wrong?

When you include jQuery the first time:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

The second script plugs itself into jQuery, and "adds" `$(...).datepicker`.

But then you are including jQuery once again:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It undoes the plugging in and therefore `$(...).datepicker` becomes undefined.

Although the first `$(document).ready` block appears before that, the anonymous callback function body is not executed until all scripts are loaded, and by then `$(...)` (`window.$` to be precise) is referring to the most recently loaded jQuery.

You would not run into this if you called `$('.dateinput').datepicker` immediately rather than in `$(document).ready` callback, but then you'd need to make sure that the target element (with class `dateinput`) is already in the document before the script, and it's generally advised to use the `ready` callback.

## Solution

If you want to use `datepicker` from jquery-ui, it would probably make most sense to include the jquery-ui script **after** bootstrap. jquery-ui 1.11.4 is compatible with jquery 1.6+ so it will work fine.

Alternatively (in particular if you are not using jquery-ui for anything else), you could try [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Comment: This was a great reminder. In my case I had already called jquery-ui from another php include file. So it's the same effect as you've correctly stated. Thanks!

Comment: i have the same error i have bootstrap.min.css,jquery-1.9.1.js,jquery-ui.js,jquery.min.js what order do i have to give

Comment: Thanks, it HELPS.

Answer (score 3):

The error is because you are including the script links at two places which will do the override and re-initialization of date-picker

```js
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dateinput').datepicker({ format: "yyyy/mm/dd" });
}); 
</script>

      <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So exclude either **src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"**

or
**src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"**

It will work..

Answer (score 2):

**if you are using ASP.NET MVC**

**Open** the layout file **"_Layout.cshtml"** or your custom one

At the part of the code you see, as below:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

**Remove** the line "*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")*"

(at the part of the code you see) past as the **latest** line, as below:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

This help me and hope helps you as well.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add three file and two css links. You can either cdn's as well.
Links for the js files and css files are as such :-

1. jQuery.dataTables.min.js
2. dataTables.bootstrap.min.js
3. dataTables.bootstrap.min.css
4. bootstrap-datepicker.css
5. bootstrap-datepicker.js

They are valid if you are using bootstrap in your project.

I hope this will help you.
Regards,
Vivek Singla

Answer (score 0):

Including more than one reference to Jquery library is the reason for the error **Only Include one reference to the Jquery library and that will resolve the issue**

Answer (score 0):

We need to add the declaration of our jQuery plugin under interface with the same name. We don’t want to mess with the jQuery source code, so we need to create our own type definition file. I’m using React/typescript so just follow these steps

1. Open nodemodules and go into types folder.
2. Go into jQuery and open jQuery.d.ts fileand add the below code into interface JQuery<TElement = HTMLElement> extends Iterable {

**daterangepicker(options?: any, callback?: Function) : any;**

I’m declaring the daterangepicker function (this is the actual function that the API expose) and setting all its arguments as any ( You can go further and use specific types, but in this case, I will keep it simple ).
Now when the typescript compiler sees our interface, it will merge it with the jQuery interface and the error is gone.
That’s all!

Answer (score -2):

This error is occur,because the function is not defined.
In my case i have called the datepicker function without including the datepicker js file that time I got this error.