# django with ajax: function not loading from source file

Tags: jquery, django, django-ajax-selects

In my Django project I'm trying to add a datepicker using jQuery. When I load page in a browser the console gives me an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

I tried the same AJAX code in a simple HTML page and it works fine there. Why is this `datepicker()` function not loading in Django from source location?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
  </script>
  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
  {% block contents %} {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I placed your code in an executable snippet where it works fine. Are there any other errors in the console? Perhaps about the script references leading to 404 errors, or conflicts?

Comment: here is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207203/uncaught-typeerror-datepicker-is-not-a-functionanonymous-function

Comment: your solution helped me to find the mistake. Thanks :) @YazanM.Al-Horani

Answer (score 0):

Let's click to the link [click](http://keith-wood.name/zip/jquery.datepick.package-5.0.1.zip)
 download the datepicker package and import any of js file to your templates

This will solve your problem