# (uncaught exception)TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Tags: testing, automation, cypress, uncaught-exception

```
it('Access URL', () => {
  cy.visit('URL')
  cy.wait(5000)
  cy.get('.login-btn').click()
  })
```

URL is working but login click is not working.
(uncaught exception)TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function --- is displayed

Trying to access url and trying to click the Login link in the website.

Comment: Maybe there is an issue such as this one [Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function(anonymous function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207203/uncaught-typeerror-datepicker-is-not-a-functionanonymous-function)

Answer (score 2):

If it takes the page more then 5 seconds to load cypress would never find the button in your code. If you can give the button an `id` it would be able to find it, but if you can't you can try to add a long timeout to the button and when the button appear on the page it will click it, for example.

```
`cy.get('.login-btn', { timeout: 30000 }).click()`
```

Comment: (uncaught exception)TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
(xhr)POST 200 /jm-ajax/get_listings/
TypeError
The following error originated from your application code, not from Cypress.

> $(...).datepicker is not a function
When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your application it will automatically fail the current test.
 The above error is getting displayed when tried the code cy.get('.login-btn',{timeout:30000}).click()

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of your comment, you have an uncaught exception in your application. That’s an indication you or a dev needs to fix something in the app. Cypress is just trying to tell you.

If you want to ignore the error, you can add this to your test

```js
it('Access URL', () => {
  cy.once('uncaught:exception', () => false);
  cy.visit('URL')
  cy.wait(5000)
  cy.get('.login-btn').click()
})
```

If you want to ignore uncaught exceptions in ALL tests you can add this to your support file. (I do NOT recommend this, I recommend fixing your application to find out why it’s throwing an exception in the first place)

```js
// support/index.js
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', () => false);
```