# How to include jQuery UI into my project using Webpack?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, reactjs, npm, webpack

I started a new project using [React Slingshot](https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot) and am trying to use [jQuery UI accordions](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/).  I have installed the jQuery UI plugin with NPM using `npm install --save jquery-ui`.  As far as I understand, Webpack automatically bundles my Javascript into a `bundles.js` based on my Webpack config, and is included on my `index.ejs` page.  However, I'm getting this error, which tells me that the jQuery UI plugin is not being loaded to the page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).accordion is not a function
```

How can I include this plugin?  Below I have included my code - let me know if there are any other files you'd like to see.

**index.ejs:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!--
  **NOTE:** This is a template for index.html. It uses ejs and htmlWebpackPlugin to generate a different index.html for each environment. htmlWebpackPlugin will dynamically add references to the scripts and styles that it bundles to this file. The generated bundles have hash-based filenames, so it's necessary to add the references dynamically.
  For more info on ejs, see http://www.embeddedjs.com/. For examples of using it with htmlWebpackPlugin, see https://github.com/jaketrent/html-webpack-template/blob/master/index.ejs
  -->
<head>
  <% if (htmlWebpackPlugin.options.trackJSToken) { %>
  <script>window._trackJs = {token: '<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.trackJSToken %>'};</script>
  <script src="https://d2zah9y47r7bi2.cloudfront.net/releases/current/tracker.js"></script>
  <% } %>

  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>Fusion Starter</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import App from './components/App';
require('./favicon.ico'); // Tell webpack to load favicon.ico
import './styles/styles.scss'; // Yep, that's right. You can import SASS/CSS files too! Webpack will run the associated loader and plug this into the page.
import './styles/spa.less';
import './styles/jquery-ui.min.css';
import './styles/jquery-ui.structure.min.css';
import './styles/jquery-ui.theme.min.css';


const store = configureStore();

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('app')
);
```

**App.js:**

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import Header from './common/Header';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <div id="content" className="ui-front">
       <div id="appContainer">
        <div id="accordionContainer">
         <div id="accordion">
          <h3 id="accountDetailsPanel">SELECT STATE AND ACCOUNT TYPE</h3>
          <div id="accountDetailsContainer" className="inner-content"></div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3",          
      autoheight: false,
      active: false,
      alwaysOpen: false,
      fillspace: false,
      collapsible: true,
//heightStyle: 'content'   //auto, fill, content
  });
});

export default App;
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "practice",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "node tools/nodeVersionCheck.js",
    "setup": "node tools/setup/setupMessage.js && npm install && node tools/setup/setup.js",
    "remove-demo": "babel-node tools/removeDemo.js",
    "start-message": "babel-node tools/startMessage.js",
    "prestart": "npm-run-all --parallel start-message remove-dist",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel test:watch open:src lint:watch",
    "open:src": "babel-node tools/srcServer.js",
    "open:dist": "babel-node tools/distServer.js",
    "lint": "esw webpack.config.* src tools --color",
    "lint:watch": "npm run lint -- --watch",
    "clean-dist": "npm run remove-dist && mkdir dist",
    "remove-dist": "rimraf ./dist",
    "prebuild": "npm run clean-dist && npm run lint && npm run test",
    "build": "babel-node tools/build.js && npm run open:dist",
    "test": "mocha tools/testSetup.js \"src/**/*.spec.js\" --reporter progress",
    "test:cover": "babel-node node_modules/isparta/bin/isparta cover --root src --report html node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- --require ./tools/testSetup.js \"src/**/*.spec.js\" --reporter progress",
    "test:cover:travis": "babel-node node_modules/isparta/bin/isparta cover --root src --report lcovonly _mocha -- --require ./tools/testSetup.js \"src/**/*.spec.js\" && cat ./coverage/lcov.info | node_modules/coveralls/bin/coveralls.js",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "open:cover": "npm run test:cover && open coverage/index.html"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "3.1.0",
    "jquery-ui": "1.12.0",
    "object-assign": "4.1.0",
    "react": "15.2.0",
    "react-dom": "15.2.0",
    "react-redux": "4.4.5",
    "react-router-redux": "4.0.5",
    "redux": "3.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.10.1",
    "babel-core": "6.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-react-display-name": "2.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "6.5.0",
    "babel-register": "6.9.0",
    "browser-sync": "2.13.0",
    "chai": "3.5.0",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "coveralls": "2.11.11",
    "cross-env": "1.0.8",
    "css-loader": "0.23.1",
    "enzyme": "2.4.1",
    "eslint": "3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "1.10.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "1.5.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "5.2.2",
    "eslint-watch": "2.1.13",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "0.9.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.22.0",
    "isparta": "4.0.0",
    "less": "2.7.1",
    "less-loader": "2.2.3",
    "mocha": "2.5.3",
    "node-sass": "3.8.0",
    "npm-run-all": "2.3.0",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "prompt": "1.0.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "15.2.0",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "1.2.3",
    "replace": "0.3.0",
    "rimraf": "2.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "4.0.0",
    "sinon": "1.17.4",
    "sinon-chai": "2.8.0",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.7",
    "webpack": "1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.6.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.12.1",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "0.0.5"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.dev.js:**

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';

export default {
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map', // more info:https://webpack.github.io/docs/build-performance.html#sourcemaps and https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
  noInfo: true, // set to false to see a list of every file being bundled.
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
    './src/index'
  ],
  target: 'web', // necessary per https://webpack.github.io/docs/testing.html#compile-and-test
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/src`, // Note: Physical files are only output by the production build task `npm run build`.
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/', // Use absolute paths to avoid the way that URLs are resolved by Chrome when they're parsed from a dynamically loaded CSS blob. Note: Only necessary in Dev.
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'), // Tells React to build in either dev or prod modes. https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html (See bottom)
      __DEV__: true
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({     // Create HTML file that includes references to bundled CSS and JS.
      template: 'src/index.ejs',
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true
      },
      inject: true
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'), loaders: ['babel']},
      {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
      {test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"},
      {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
      {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'},
      {test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i, loaders: ['file']},
      {test: /\.ico$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'},
      {test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap']},
      {test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'sass?sourceMap']},
      {test: /\.less$/, loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'less?sourceMap']}
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Did you take a look at this answer? It seems to be exactly what you need http://stackoverflow.com/a/34003565/646156. Basically you need to require jquery first, and then jquery-ui.

Comment: Just tried that answer out, in this line:
    `var $ = require("jquery"), require("jquery-ui");`
It says "Unexpected token" at the third parentheses of the entire line.

Comment: it's a typo, it should read '$ = require("jquery"), $ui = require("jquery-ui");' Actually you don't need $ui since jquery-ui will augment $, but the problem here is invalid JS syntax

Comment: I made the change to `$ = require("jquery"), $ui = require("jquery-ui");` and now I'm getting the following error upon building with webpack:

`ERROR in ./src/components/App.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js' in C:\practice\PracticeApp\src\components @ ./src/components/App.js 49:12-32`

Any ideas?  I have definitely run NPM install on my project and I included the 'resolve' property into my webpack config file as listed in the answer you linked.

Comment: Did you `npm install jquery-ui`? Check the alias, is this path in `node_modules`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery-ui and webpack, how to manage it into module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998262/jquery-ui-and-webpack-how-to-manage-it-into-module)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and it worked for me:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
}),

// ...

alias: {
  jquery: 'jquery/src/jquery',
  'jquery-ui': 'jquery-ui/ui',
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still new to webpack, but https://stackoverflow.com/a/39230057/1798643 worked for me:

```
npm i -S jquery-ui-bundle
```

Then use:

```
require("jquery-ui-bundle");
```

If you try to alias jquery-ui module, you're in for trouble since its in:

```
./build/release.js
```

Which you can alias in webpack config:

```
alias: {
  "jquery-ui": "jquery-ui/build/release.js",
  ...
```

But that will lead to more trouble since its inner requires will not be resolved:

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'shelljs'
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'download.jqueryui.com/lib/jquery-ui'
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'node-packager'
```

And so on...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by setting gloabl variables **window.$** and **window.jQuery** after plugin functions were imported:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'webpack-jquery-ui'
import 'webpack-jquery-ui/css'
//console.log($.ui.dialog)   //check new plugin function
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
```

It also works when you need more jQuery plugin, such as jstree, datatables, e.g.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'webpack-jquery-ui'
import 'jstree'
//console.log($.fn.jstree)   //check new plugin function
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
```

The tip is **window.$ = window.jQuery = $;** after plugin were imported. Otherwise you would see $.ui.dialog is defined in main.js, but it is undefined in other script files