# use jquery-ui with webpack having a particular file structure

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, webpack

I would like you to help/suggest the best way to use datepicker from jquery-ui having the following file structure:

```
-single_pages
  -admin
    -admin.js
    -webpack.config.js
  -common
    -DatesFilter
      -DatesFilter.js
  -node_modules
  -package.json
```

I already installed `jquery-ui`

My `webpack.config.js` file is:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
        'jquery': require.resolve('jquery'),
    },
    root: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, './../admin'),
      path.resolve(__dirname, './../common')
    ],
    extensions: ['', '.js'],
    fallback: path.resolve(__dirname, './../node_modules')
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    fallback: path.resolve(__dirname, './../node_modules')
  },
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  externals: {
      // require("jquery") is external and available
      //  on the global var jQuery
      "jquery": "jQuery"
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      "$":"jquery",
      "jQuery":"jquery",
      "window.jQuery":"jquery"
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, './')
        ],
        loader: "babel-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, './../common'),
        babelrc: false,
        loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
        query: { // load the same presets as in the .babelrc file, but in a way that resolves in the parent directory
          presets: [require.resolve('babel-preset-es2015'),     require.resolve('babel-preset-react'),
        require.resolve('babel-preset-stage-0')]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I'm using React.js.

I import `DatesFilter.js` inside `admin.js`. I get to see the component. The problem comes when I want to use the datepicker.

`DatesFilter.js` uses `datepicker` from `jquery-ui`

I'm using: `import { datepicker } from 'jquery-ui'` inside `DatesFilter.js` but it keeps saying `TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function`

What can I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try importing just the module, see this link [jquery-ui-and-webpack-how-to-manage-it-into-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998262/jquery-ui-and-webpack-how-to-manage-it-into-module)

in your case you would `import "jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker"`

Comment: Thank you very much