# How to make ui.sortable work with webpack?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use ui.sortable in my Angular project and I keep getting this error `element.sortable is not a function`. I'm using Angular 1.6.3 and Webpack. I tried to load this library in several ways and none works.

`require('jquery-ui/ui/core');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widget');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/mouse');
require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/sortable');`

Earlier I was using `require('jquery-ui-sortable-npm');` which has jQueryUI core and sortable pluging provided.
 I'm using selectize which is also using jQueryUI sortable and it works just fine. Does anyone succeeded to make this work?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem

Comment: See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998262/jquery-ui-and-webpack-how-to-manage-it-into-module, I solved the issue by adding  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      "$":"jquery",
      "jQuery":"jquery",
      "window.jQuery":"jquery"
    }),
to my webpack.config.js