# Should I still use Gemfile's javascript library when using yarn with Rails 5.1?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, webpack, yarnpkg

I'm trying to get some jQuery stuff in Rails 5.1.
Since the jQuery support is dropped (by default) I'm getting some hard time to find the exact workflow I should use.

At first I would try some Ajax stuffs but then I realized in the web developer console that '$' was not defined. This confirming that jQuery is indeed not installed by default.

**1.** The first thing I did is simply put a hard coded jquery cdn script in the application layout view, something like this in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This worked. But I guess that this is not the supported way of doing it.

**2.** Then I tried with installing jquery using yarn, since I have a Rails 5.1 installation with yarn already installed.

- I ran `yarn add jquery` then `yarn` *(seems this last is not necessary)*
- I added `//= require jquery` to the `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file

This worked too. 
*Edit: I just noticed that there is a `rails yarn:install` command, should I use that instead of the terminal native yarn command?*

But then I wanted to play with some jQuery-ui stuffs. Noticing that the package `jquery-ui` exists in yarn, I did the same thing:

- I ran `yarn add jquery-ui` then `yarn` again
- I added `//= require jquery-ui` to the `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file right below the `jquery` one

But this did not work. Then I noticed that some people refer to jquery gems, particularly the gems `jquery-rails` and `jquery-ui-rails`.

My question is despite having a *working* yarn *pipeline*, should I still use the related gems?

In my case should I only use these both gems? Or should I only install the `jquery-ui-rails` one since my jquery installation with yarn is working?

I'm sorry but this asset management thing is not yet get into my head..
And still not yet starting webpack stuffs

Answer (score 3):

I made it work without Rails gems and with yarn packages.

**Instead of this**

Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

**Solution.**

add yarn packages in package.json

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "jquery-ui-dist": "1.12.1",
    "jquery-ujs": "1.2.2",
    .. more packages here
  }
}
```

Note! it uses package jquery-ui-dist (not jquery-ui).

application.js:

```
//= require jquery/dist/jquery
//= require jquery-ujs
//= require jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui
```

About jquery-ui packages:
the jQuery-ui package on NPM isn't pre-built and therefore doesn't contain jquery-ui.js; the package will either need built before use or all the widgets included/used individually. Read more in this discussion - 
[jquery-ui and webpack, how to manage it into module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998262/jquery-ui-and-webpack-how-to-manage-it-into-module/42465244).

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at `node_modules` folder in the root of the project - there you will find all installed with YARN packages and there should be folder with library which you added to YARN and want to use.