# TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function with webpack

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, webpack, webpack-2

I'm trying to migrate my application from requirejs to webpack 2 but i'm having trouble.

My webpack config :

```
 rules: [
            // rules for modules (configure loaders, parser options, etc.)

            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, "src")
                ],
                exclude: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, "app/demo-files")
                ],

                enforce: "pre",
                enforce: "post",

            },

            {
                test: /underscore/,
                loader: 'expose-loader?_'
            },
            {
                test: /howler/,
                loader: 'expose-loader?Howl'
            },
            {
                test: /pathfinding/,
                loader: 'expose-loader?PF'
            },
            {
                test: /stats/,
                loader: 'expose-loader?Stats'
            },
            {
                test: /datgui/,
                loader: 'expose-loader?dat.gui'
            },
            { test: /jquery/,
                loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery,$=jquery,this=>window'
            },
            {
                test: /jquery-ui/,
                use: [
                    'expose-loader?$',
                    'imports-loader?this=>window,jquery'
                ]
            }
```

And in plugin section :

```
plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                "$":"libs/jquery/jquery.min",
                "jQuery":"libs/jquery/jquery.min",
                "window.jQuery":"libs/jquery/jquery.min"
            }),
        ]
```

But when i do this i have the following error :

```
Game.js:48 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
    at Game.init (Game.js:48)
    at Object.<anonymous> (init.js:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (init.js:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap aa1ecbe…:678)
```

Can you help me with this trouble ? I think the problem is with the import of jquery but i don't know how to resolve the issue...

Thanks

Comment: i didnt see the configuration of webpack for tooltip, you'll need to add jquery.tooltip?

Comment: Did you follow all of the instructions here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998262/jquery-ui-and-webpack-how-to-manage-it-into-module

Comment: by adding this to my alias :
      "jquery-ui": "libs/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js",
            // bind to modules;
            modules: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules") i have another error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'fontSpy' of undefined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

Comment: @nico these errors arise when libraries do not load properly. `Cannot set property 'fontSpy' of undefined` will mean that an object or variable is `null` and you're trying to set a property of it. You will want to review your code for typos or other errors. You may want to use tools like jshint.

Comment: `tooltip` is a JQuery plugin provided by Bootstrap.

Comment: Hi, did you resolve this? I'm stuck with the exact same problem

Answer (score -1):

Try adding

```
Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
```

To your plugins