# Wordpress include jQuery-ui Datepicker

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui, npm, webpack, gulp

I try to use jquery-ui datepicker in my Wordpress theme, but I failed with it.
I use npm as package manager, so I tryed to install it with npm, but this didn't work, so I installed it manually and downloaded jquery-ui from the website and require it into my main.js file.

```
var $ = jQuery;
var axios = require("axios");
var datetimepicker = require("./jquery-ui.js");

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dp").datepicker();
});
```

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Comment: You need to load it the same way your currently loading jQuery. Jquery predates imports/require and doesn't support them well

Comment: How are you running require? Are you using requirejs?

Comment: @Liam i use webpack
I doesn't load jQuery. Wordpress does this for me:

    wp_enqueue_script( 'laabs-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/app.js', array("jquery"), '20151215', true );

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery-ui and webpack, how to manage it into module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998262/jquery-ui-and-webpack-how-to-manage-it-into-module)

Comment: That said if wordpress is loading jquery then webpack won't be able to resolve the dependencies. You'll like just need to include using a good ole fashioned `<script>` tag

Comment: BTW `var $ = jQuery;` is doing nothing here, jquery already aliases `jQuery` as `$` globally.

Comment: I suppose it allows you to alias `$` for something else if that's your bag...

Comment: i still have this problem what should i load with a old fashioned <script> tag?