# Typescript TypeError: draggable is not a function

Tags: jquery, typescript, jquery-ui, vue.js, typing

I am using typescript with vue and jquery ui.

I am getting error as "**TypeError: item.$element.draggable is not a function**".

What am I  missing in this code. I have included jquery-ui also as can be seen from following files. I want to use jquery ui plugins into my code.

I googled many places but none of the solutions are working for me. I have also added typings for jquery and jquery ui.

My **floatingmenu.ts** file

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import $ from 'jquery';
import anime from 'animejs';
import 'jquery-ui';

@Component
export default class FloatingMenuComponent extends Vue {

    mounted() {

        var menu = new Menu("#myMenu");
        var item1 = new Item("list","#FF5C5C");
        var item2 = new Item("torso", "#FF5C5C");
        var item3 = new Item("social-facebook", "#5CD1FF");
        var item4 = new Item("paypal", "#FFF15C");
        var item5 = new Item("link", "#64F592");

        menu.add(item1);
        menu.add(item2);
        menu.add(item3);
        menu.add(item4);
        menu.add(item5);
        $(document).delay(50).queue(function(next) {
            menu.open();
            next();
            $(document).delay(1000).queue(function(next) {
                menu.close();
                next();
            });
        });



    }
}

var timeOut: number;

class Menu {
    $element: any;
    size: number;
    first:any = null;
    last:any = null;
    timeOut: null;
    hasMoved: boolean;
    status: string;
    constructor(menu: string) {
        this.$element = $(menu);
        this.size = 0;
        this.first = null;
        this.last = null;
        this.timeOut = null;
        this.hasMoved = false;
        this.status = "closed";
    }

    add(item: Item) {
        var menu = this;
        if (this.first == null) {
            this.first = item;
            this.last = item;
            this.first.$element.on("mouseup", function() {
                if (menu.first.isMoving) {
                    menu.first.isMoving = false;        
                } else {
                    menu.click();
                }
            }); 
            item.$element.draggable(
                {
                    start: function() {
                        menu.close();
                        item.isMoving = true;
                    }  
                },
                {
                    drag: function() {
                        if (item.next) {
                            item.next.updatePosition();
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    stop: function() {
                        item.isMoving = false;
                        item.next.moveTo(item);
                    }
                }
            );
        } else {
            this.last.next = item;
            item.prev = this.last;
            this.last = item;
        }
        this.$element.after(item.$element);


    }

    open() {
        this.status = "open";
        var current = this.first.next;
        var iterator = 1;
        var head = this.first;
        var sens = head.$element.css("left") < head.$element.css("right") ? 1 : -1;
        while (current != null) {
            anime({
                targets: current.$element[0],
                left: parseInt(head.$element.css("left"), 10) + (sens * (iterator * 50)),
                top: head.$element.css("top"),
                duration: 500
            });
            iterator++;
            current = current.next;
        }    
    }

    close() {
        this.status = "closed";
        var current = this.first.next;
        var head = this.first;
        var iterator = 1;
        while (current != null) {
            anime({
                targets: current.$element[0],
                left: head.$element.css("left"),
                top: head.$element.css("top"),
                duration: 500
            });
            iterator++;
            current = current.next;
        }
    }

    click() {
        if (this.status == "closed") {
            this.open();
        } else {
            this.close();
        }
    }

}

class Item {
    $element: any;
    icon: any;
    prev: any = null;
    next:any = null;
    isMoving: boolean;
    constructor(icon: string, backgroundColor: string) {
        this.$element = $(document.createElement("div"));
        this.icon = icon;
        this.$element.addClass("item");
        this.$element.css("background-color", backgroundColor);
        var i = document.createElement("i");
        $(i).addClass("fi-" + icon);
        this.$element.append(i);
        this.prev = null;
        this.next = null;
        this.isMoving = false;
        var element = this;
        this.$element.on("mousemove", function() {
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
            timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
                if (element.next && element.isMoving) {
                    element.next.moveTo(element);
                } 
            }, 10);
        });
    }

    moveTo(item: { $element: { css: { (arg0: string): void; (arg0: string): void; }; }; }) {
        anime({
            targets: this.$element[0],
            left: item.$element.css("left"),
            top: item.$element.css("top"),
            duration: 700,
            elasticity: 500
        });
        if (this.next) {
            this.next.moveTo(item);
        }
    }

    updatePosition() {    
        anime({
            targets: this.$element[0],
            left: this.prev.$element.css("left"),
            top: this.prev.$element.css("top"),
            duration: 200
        });

        if (this.next) {
            this.next.updatePosition();
        }
    }
}
```

My floatingmenu.ts.html

```
<template>
    <div class="center menu">
        <div id="myMenu"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script src="./floatingmenu.ts"></script>
```

Comment: So it basically is what you think it is, jQuery UI is not being loaded or found. Or something is conflicting with it and it's not loading properly. When you view the Source Code of the resulting page, are all the `<script>` tags where they need to be? Any other console errors before? Does your code validate in jshint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It required to provide alias for the library as I was referencing dist of jquery-ui.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40441253/9263418