# Exclude a package from Hot Module Replacement

Tags: vue.js, webpack-hmr

I have a Vue app that uses Jquery Mobile. In the Vue.config.js I added the webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()

```
plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]
```

The app was running before adding this plugin, but with withHotModuleReplacementPlugin added

```
This relative module was not found:

* ../external/requirejs/depend!./jquery.ui.widget[jquery] in 
./node_modules/jquery-mobile-build/js/jquery.mobile.widget.js
```

Rather than spend hours trying to fix this error, I would like to exclude jquery.mobile. How do I exclude a package from HMR?

Comment: What version of Vue CLI are you using?

Comment: Without your code file code and knowing how are you adding jQueryUI to your project this is going to be hard to debug. This stack overflow post may help point you in the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998262/jquery-ui-and-webpack-how-to-manage-it-into-module/39230057

Comment: Vue is version 2.6.10

I'm not sure what code file is relevant. In the vue.config I just added the one line above. 

My issue is with jquery.mobile. Not jquery.ui.. Reinstalling it is not an option. There must be a way to exclude code from the HMR process.

Answer (score 0):

This was my bad... I was putting the webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin() outside of the plugins area, on the same level as plugins, resolve, and module.

I put it in with the other plugins and it worked. No errors.