# how to properly manage jquery-ui with webpack

Tags: symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

I'm currently moving to webpack-encore on my symfony app and I'm struggling with the jquery-ui library.

in my first file `app.js` I wanted to use easing

```js
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/effect';


// Smooth scrolling using jQuery easing
$('a.js-scroll-trigger[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function () {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: (target.offset().top - 70)
            }, 1000, "easeInOutExpo");
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

It has taken me some time to figure out that it was in `jqueryui/ui/effect.js` file....

now In my `view.js` I'd like to use draggable element :

```js
//css
import '../css/event.css';

//js 
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/plugin';

$("span[class='draggable']").draggable({
    snap : '.dropdown'
});
```

And of course it doesn't work I get a

> ERROR: $("span[class='draggable']").draggable() is not a function

Is there a proper way to load all jquery-ui like in good all days ? with a simple

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is tested

Install jquery-ui ref: [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-jquery-ui)

```
$ npm install webpack-jquery-ui
```

and then

```
require('webpack-jquery-ui/draggable');

$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
```

Comment: Why using `import`? because in the [doc](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/webpack-encore/require-import#import-versus-require) they explained that it was the official ECMAscript specification. Then my javascripts are at the very bottom of my HTML page, as such they are the ultimate thing to load and I never need `$(document).ready`.  Anyway I tried your suggestion and it doesn't change anything

Comment: I have tested in my project and modified the answer with my working code, still when I use "import" it gives me the same error as you got. so I recommend you to use "require"

Comment: I have tried your solution. It works effectively but it has no link with the use of `require`or `import`, it's just that you used `webpack-jquery-ui` instead of  `jquery-ui`. The original library isn't natively compatible with webpack ?

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998262/jquery-ui-and-webpack-how-to-manage-it-into-module

Comment: effectively the native library is not nice with us. In the (Doc)[https://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.12/#official-package-on-npm] they specify clearly that you need now to import each widget individually. I'll use your solution and the `webpack-jquery-ui` for the moment. thx