# Webpack/jQuery: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" when importing other modules

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, webpack

I have a project that I'm using Webpack for, and I am trying to use the autocomplete feature of jQuery-UI.  However, whenever I import jQuery-UI into my `app.js` file using `import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/autocomplete', it breaks jQuery and I get the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed when I changed `import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/autocomplete` into `require(jquery-ui/ui/widgets/autocomplete)` in my `apps.js` file (or index.js or whatever your entry file for Webpack is).

Again, I have no idea why this works, but it does, and I can't argue with that.

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/42465244/10757677 for the inspiration.